# JobRunr integration with JonRunnr causing SQLTransientConnectionException and connection refused error

Tags: java, spring, jobrunr

I am facing an issue while running integration test cases after integrating JobRunr with JonRunnr. The stack trace shows a StorageException with a SQLTransientConnectionException, which is caused by a connection timeout. Additionally, there is a PSQLException indicating that the connection to localhost on port 57310 is refused. I have verified the hostname, port, and postmaster settings, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this and successfully run the integration tests?

Error Trace :

```
2023-12-11T17:11:07.353Z ERROR 2654049 --- [      Thread-62] org.jobrunr.server.ServerZooKeeper       : Error when signalling that BackgroundJobServer stopped



org.jobrunr.storage.StorageException: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-14 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.

    at org.jobrunr.storage.sql.common.DefaultSqlStorageProvider.signalBackgroundJobServerStopped(DefaultSqlStorageProvider.java:99) ~[jobrunr-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

    at org.jobrunr.storage.ThreadSafeStorageProvider.signalBackgroundJobServerStopped(ThreadSafeStorageProvider.java:64) ~[jobrunr-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

    at org.jobrunr.server.ServerZooKeeper.stop(ServerZooKeeper.java:60) ~[jobrunr-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

    at org.jobrunr.server.BackgroundJobServer.stopZooKeepers(BackgroundJobServer.java:263) ~[jobrunr-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

    at org.jobrunr.server.BackgroundJobServer.stop(BackgroundJobServer.java:139) ~[jobrunr-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

    at org.jobrunr.server.ServerZooKeeper.stopServer(ServerZooKeeper.java:134) ~[jobrunr-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]

Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-14 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at org.jobrunr.storage.sql.common.DefaultSqlStorageProvider.signalBackgroundJobServerStopped(DefaultSqlStorageProvider.java:95) ~[jobrunr-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

    ... 6 common frames omitted

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:57320 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]

    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]

    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]

    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]

    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297) ~[postgresql-42.6.0.jar:42.6.0]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:733) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:712) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]

    ... 1 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]

    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
```